# What type of a project should I create in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 if I want to create a console application?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I find the list of project types/templates utterly confusing. Which one must I select if all I want to do is create a simple console application?

I won't want Gradle or Maven because the only library/jar file I will want to access, I already have the jar file for, so I'll just add a reference to it manually.

[image]

Comment: Just click next and select command line application. You don't need to select anything here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `File > New > Project`
2. Select `Java`
3. Select `Next`
4. (Optionally) Select `Command Line App`
5. Select `Next`
6. Provide Project name, location etc
7. Select `Finish`

You'll now have a simple project, like so:

[image]